# setting input stream to return EOF repeatedly in loop

Tags: c

I have written this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int input=0;

    while(input=getchar())               //TARGET
        printf("%d\n",input);
}
```

I have intentionally used loop without `!=EOF`. And I am asking about what bit is set after pressing **ctrl+d** as it keeps printing *-1* even without entering any input - indicating that some error bit must've been set for the stream which is making **getchar()** return **-1** repeatedly - I want to know what that is. & what is going behind this entire thing.

Plus how to reset the stream to a normal state again.

It is an input on linux.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You have indicated the end of stream, and you have a loop that keeps telling you that. Perhaps you mean to use `while((input=getchar()) != EOF)`

Comment: @WeatherVane I have edited the part after the code.

Comment: getchar() returns EOF when it can't read anything.  EOD is defined to be -1 on your system.  Clearly you should be checking for EOF.  The advice not to use the eof() function in a loop is good because it only returns true AFTER a read has failed.  But when you do the read you need to check for EOF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The stream's `end-of-file` flag is set when it reaches EOF. This is the flag that the `feof()` function tests.

If you want to read past this, you can use the [`clearerr()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/clearerr/) function. This clears both the error and EOF indicators (I don't think there's a way to clear just one of them).

```
int main(void)
{
    int input=0;

    while(input=getchar()) {              //TARGET
        printf("%d\n",input);
        if (feof(stdin) || ferror(stdin)) {
            clearerr(stdin);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that whether you actually can read anything after EOF is both system- and device-dependent. If `stdin` is a terminal or ordinary file, EOF is a temporary condition (the user can keep typing on the terminal after entering <kbd>Ctl-d</kbd>, and more data can be added to a file). But once you get to the end of a TCP stream, nothing can be added to it.

Comment: is anything wrong with the question? I don't know why it has been downvoted

Comment: It might have been downvoted before you edited to clarify what you meant.

Comment: Not by me, despite my negative remark. Something has to be *really bad* for me to downvote, and this one is quite well presented. I meant I could not see what you are having trouble with.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus It was for the reasons Barmar stated -- removed it and upvoted now.

Comment: Detail: if one cares.  The after `EOF` discussion relates to `EOF` due to "end-of-file".  `EOF` due to rare input error (e. g. parity error) is another matter as the reason for the input error may be transitory and a `clearerr()` will readily clear the _error flag_ and next input is fine.  OTOH an input error (e. g. file open in write mode) will be permanent.  A `clearer()` will clear, yet the next input will error and return `EOF`.

Answer (score -1):

I have tested a clone of your snippet in several environments. First of all, the Ctrl+D does not always emulate an EOF. In Windows it is Ctrl+Z. A reliable way to test is to use a redirect:

test.exe < sample.txt

Without this, in the "interactive mode", you can see the difference between the following:

a a a Ctrl+Z
97 97 97 10 (10 is the line break)

Ctrl+Z
-1

This is not to say that the "character" is -1. Rather, there is nothing to read. So basically an EOF.

Now when you load a file with a redirect, the while loop will never stop because -1 is not zero. Yet getchar() keeps returning -1.

Hope this provides some perspective.